# Webpack with npm: Module Dynamic Import

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, tensorflow.js

I'm adding some optional functionality to an existing project that uses npm and webpack. This functionality makes use of a rather large module (tfjs to be exact), and I'd like to prevent loading it by default, since it approximately doubles the application's payload. Ideally, I'd be able to import it dynamically for users who navigate to this functionality.

Anyway, I'm the first to admit I'm totally out of my depth here. I'm not very well versed in webpack in particular. So my question is:

What is a general strategy for dynamically loading an npm module dependency?

I've looked at code splitting - this seems to only work for sources and not dependencies. I'm considering creating a subdirectory with a separate package.json and node_modules/ and exporting them as static resources.

Answer (score 0):

Code Splitting should actually work for you! It works for sources, but it will only bundle the dependencies actually used for each source into a chunk. So if you just make sure that you only import the dependency in on pages where it's used and set up your code splitting correctly you should get the behavior you describe above. Without more detail about your projects structure It's not really possible to to give a more detailed answer with the exact webpack config (and honestly, I probably wouldn't take the time to set it up for you even if you did provide that detail) but I think with code splitting you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as schu34 said, you're definitely on the right track.

In general, the setup is basically:

1) Ensure the library is already loaded on your page, either by another module or by a script tag. It should be exposed on the `window` object. For example, jQuery is exposed as both `window.$` and `window.jquery` on most sites, and both work.

2) install the library as a dev dependency

3) in Webpack, configure the library as an external. This will allow you to import the lib in your source without including it in the output. See: [Webpack Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

4) If you use Flow, this can be a bit tricky. I tend to just make a const ( `const $ = window.$` ) in this case because I'm lazy, but there are better solutions available.

I hope this helps.